# Text color is not correct

Tags: c++, opengl

```
void text(string str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, str[i]);
    }
}

void render(void)
{
    int width  = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    int height = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    if (height == 0) height = 1;
    GLfloat aspect = (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, aspect, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    // Top view - top left
    glViewport(0, 0, width/2, height/2);
    glScissor(0, 0, width/2, height/2);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    PilotView(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glRasterPos3f(-0.1f, -0.1f, 4.0f);
    text("Front");
    diode();

    // Corner view - top right
    glViewport(width/2, 0, width/2, height/2);
    glScissor(width/2, 0, width/2, height/2);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    PilotView(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f, -90.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glRasterPos3f(4.0f, -0.1f, 0.1f);
    text("Right");
    diode();

    // Front view - bottom left
    glViewport(0, height/2, width/2, height/2);
    glScissor(0, height/2, width/2, height/2);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    PilotView(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f, 90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glRasterPos3f(-0.1f, 4.0f, 0.0f);
    text("Top");
    diode();

    // Right view - bottom right
    glViewport(width/2, height/2, width/2, height/2);
    glScissor(width/2, height/2, width/2, height/2);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    PilotView(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f, 20.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glRasterPos3f(-0.1f, 4.0f, 0.0f);
    text("Fro4nt");
    diode();

    glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

I'm not sure where the white "Front" and the yellow "Top"/"Right" is coming from (in terms of color).  They all should be black.  Does anyone know what the issue is?

Here is what the output looks like:
[image]

Comment: Those funky looking beveled cubes, I am assuming those are your "diodes?" I am pretty sure the color that is being used by the font renderer is tracking the "current" color set by those cubes. I would like to see the implementation of `diode (...)` added to your question if you could, that would be very helpful. In the meantime, something like `glColor4f (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);` immediately before `text (...)` would probably solve your problem.

Comment: woops, just added diode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suspected, this may come as a shock but `glRasterPos (...)` actually tracks the "current" color when you call that function. That is, whatever color was set before `glRasterPos (...)` was called, applies as the "current color" for drawing operations at that position. Think of it almost as the rasterizer's analog to `glVertex (...)`, as I will explain below.

You need to set the current color before you call `glRasterPos (...)`, to that end you should remove the `glColor3f (...)` call completely from your `text (...)` function, or perhaps modify that function to do both - set the color and then the raster pos, then draw the text.

---

#### [glRasterPos — specify the raster position for pixel operations](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glRasterPos.xml):

> The current raster position consists of three window coordinates (x, y, z), a clip coordinate value (w), an eye coordinate distance, a valid bit, and associated color data and texture coordinates.